# Average with a condition and Order specific Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, average

I develop an application for a railway company. I have a problem to calculate an average with a condition specific.
To better understand I will give an example

Here's an example of data from the database:

```
---------check----------------HR---------------Serie-----NameStation

06/12/2016 05:57:00     06/12/2016 05:57:07     7100    Station A
06/12/2016 05:59:30     06/12/2016 05:59:40     7100    Station B
06/12/2016 06:00:00     06/12/2016 06:00:35     7100    Station C

07/12/2016 05:57:00     07/12/2016 05:56:34     7100    Station A
07/12/2016 06:00:30     07/12/2016 05:58:59     7100    Station B
07/12/2016 06:01:00     07/12/2016 05:59:46     7100    Station C

08/12/2016 05:57:00     08/12/2016 05:56:25     7100    Station A
08/12/2016 05:59:30     08/12/2016 05:59:28     7100    Station B
08/12/2016 06:00:00     08/12/2016 06:01:50     7100    Station C
```

I have  data for each train over a month. .
The train every day has a planned itinerary (it passes through 3 stations at specified times = theoretical time which is the column check, the type is date `dd/ mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`).
My HR column is the time at which the train is really passing at the station  = real time which has the same format as the check column.

My goal is to calculate the average of the HR column over a month.
However over a month, it happens that there is a change of schedule.
I need to calcluate the average of the column HR if only the serie has the same routine = same theoretical time (column check) for the 3 station

In this example the serie 7100 has a different planned itinerary   for the date 07/12/2016 at the station B and C. then I need to calculate the average only for the 06/12/2016 and 08/12/2016.
And the average for 07/12/2016 separatly.
OR better to calculate the average for the most recurent planned itinerary (station A+B+C same time at the column check).

the result should be

```
    check    HR       Serie     StationName
05:57:00    05:56:46    7100    Station A
05:59:30    05:59:34    7100    Station B
06:00:00    06:01:13    7100    Station C

05:57:00    05:56:34    7100    Station A
06:00:30    05:58:59    7100    Station B
06:10:00    05:59:46    7100    Station C
```

I tried to use `GROUP BY` but I lose some information, because it will calculate the average for 07/12/2016 at the station A with the others days.

Is it possible to check for each day if the series has the same route/same time for both station -->then calculate the average ?
Or is it possible to comapre the routine for each day to a reference day?

Here's my code:

```
    SELECT check,
       TO_CHAR( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + AVG( HR - TRUNC( HR ) ), 'HH24:MI:SS' )
         AS "AVG(HR)",
       serie,
       name
GROUP BY check, serie, name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions. What is the data type of `check` (bad column name, it conflicts with an Oracle keyword) and `hr`? Are they supposed to be all on the same date (or else to be abstract times-of-day with no connection to any specific date)? Then - what is the problem with your current query, what information are you losing?

Comment: Redha Ben I wondered why the `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`?  This limits the result set to only the subset of records where the same combination of `CHECK`-`SERIE`-`NAME` appears more than once.  I would guess that you want to avoiding averaging an item when there is only one representative, but wondered whether your missing data include those `CHECK`-`SERIE`-`NAME` that only appear once?    Thanks

Comment: Thanks guy to try to help me. I edit the post can ou check plz.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

For the persons who will have the same problem:
the solution is to add a column where I put all times of the column check for each train (data_with_timelist) in each row and after I group by

```
with data as(    
    select t.*,    
    trunc(chck) chck_date,    
    numtodsinterval(chck-trunc(chck), 'DAY') chck_time,  
    dense_rank() over(partition by serie order by chck-trunc(chck)) dr  
    from t    
)    
, data_with_timelist as (    
    select d.*,    
    listagg(to_char(dr,'fm00X')) within group(order by dr) over(partition by serie, chck_date) dr_list    
    from data d    
)    
select serie, namestation,  
to_char(min(chck_date) + chck_time, 'hh24:mi:ss') chck_time,  
to_char(  
    cast(  
        to_timestamp(min(chck_date)) + chck_time + numtodsinterval(avg(hr-chck), 'DAY')  
        as timestamp(0)  
    )  
    , 'hh24:mi:ss'  
) avg_hr_time  
from data_with_timelist    
group by serie, dr_list, chck_time, namestation    
order by serie, dr_list, chck_time, namestation;  

     SERIE NAMESTATION            CHCK_TIM AVG_HR_T  
---------- ---------------------- -------- --------  
      7100 Station A              05:57:00 05:56:46  
      7100 Station B              05:59:30 05:59:34  
      7100 Station C              06:00:00 06:01:13  
      7100 Station A              05:57:00 05:56:34  
      7100 Station B              06:00:30 05:58:59  
      7100 Station C              06:10:00 05:59:46
```